# How to match the values of two array in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to match the values of 'this.TAG' with the values of 'this.et'.I used the match method. but it does not match the values of 'this.TAG'. **Guide me:** What is the best way to match two arrays.
Below is my code..

.ts

```
this.image_url = [
  { word: 'hi', img: 'user.png' },
  { word: 'hlo', img: 'user.png' },
];
this.TAG=  ["hi", "hello   hii", "hi", "bye", "aa", "Sd", "Sent now", "hlo", "check tick", "check again", "hi hiii wer", "hi", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI"];

ngOnInit() {
  for(let i=0; i<this.TAG.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.TAG);
      console.log(i);
      this.et[i]= this.image_url.map(e => e.word);
      console.log(this.et[i]);
      if(this.TAG[i].match(this.et[i])) {
        console.log(this.image_url);
        this.show=true;
        console.log(this.show);
      } else {
        console.log("no hii");
      }
    },100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you descibe what you mean by "match two arrays"? Also, please format your code pretties, ths is very difficult to read. Furthermore, this question has nothing to do with Angular or Ionic. You seem to be asking about an algorithm.

Comment: where is your array : `this.et`

Comment: this.et[i]= this.image_url.map(e => e.word);
        console.log(this.et[i]);
this is 'this.et'. I want to match

Comment: I used match method to check each value of array that (Eg-- is there any value 'hi' in this TAG)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```js
    this.image_url = [
        { word: 'hi', img: 'user.png' },
        { word: 'hlo', img: 'user.png' },
        { word: 'hloll', img: 'user.png' },
        ];
  this.TAG=  ["hi", "hello   hii", "hi", "bye", "aa", "Sd", "Sent now", "hlo", "check tick", "check again", "hi hiii wer", "hi", "HI", "HI", "HI", "HI"];
  let groups= this.image_url.filter(({word}) =>   this.TAG.includes(word));
  console.log('Output:',groups);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```